# 2017 MacBook Air - MacOS Sierra reinstall fails

Tags: macos

I am trying to reinstall MacOS on a 2017 MacBook Air. I turn the computer on and go to internet recovery mode. I deleted the contents of the SSD using the disk utility. Then I went to “reinstall MacOS Sierra”. At the end of the install, I get the error “an error occurred while preparing the installation”. In the log file, I see the error “no app was found with bundle ID com.apple.installassistant.Sierra to upgrade to 12.6.03”

Please help! I come from the windows world and I am not sure where to go from here. If I make a boot image on a jump drive I would have to use a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you also deleted the recovery partition. Using a High Sierra installer on a USB stick is your best way forward. Ideally you'd do this on a Mac, but you can go to this page [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683), and just move the .app to a FAT-formatted, bootable, USB drive and your Mac will recognize it.